# Which HTTP method with AWS API Gateway

Tags: http, aws-api-gateway

I am constructing an API gateway to go with my Lmbda functions. I have a few methods I am not sure which HTTP method to us with:

- An API call that adds a like to the database - I am currently using POST for but am passing the data in using resource paths. Would it be better to use another method?

Answer (score 1):

You can use whatever HTTP method for your Lambda function.

If you want to follow the ReSTFul API style to create your API, you can use the HTTP method based on the purpose of your Lambda function or your API.

You can have more information in this wiki. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer